# Best way to have single View/ViewModel/Xaml link to multiple Json resource files in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Inside my application I have many help pages, which all have a similar layout - header and bodytext.

The way I have it structured at the moment, for every single Help page I have a View, ViewModel, .xaml and .json file.

The trouble is that my app has bloated to the point where I have about 20 help pages (don't ask) and copy and pasting these for each help file is obviously inefficient and error prone. What I'd like to have is a single HelpViewModel, HelpView, Page_Help.xml, and then for every help page a different .json file with the relevant textual resources.

I cannot figure out how to achieve this despite looking through the existing MvvmCross topics.

So my XAML has a heading that looks like this:

```
<TextView
  style="@style/HelpTextTitle"
  local:MvxBind="{'Text':'Path':'TextSource','Converter':'Language','ConverterParameter':'Heading1'}}"
/>
```

The json file that has the same name as the ViewModel (and gets linked by some automagic) looks like this:

```
{
  "Heading1":"Sample Help Heading",
}
```

And I have a HelpViewModel that can accept an argument - say the name of the json file

```
public string HeaderFile { get; private set; }
public HelpViewModel (string headerFile)
{
  HeaderFile = headerFile;
}
```

The json files are currently associated with the ViewModels I think via this class:

```
public class TextProviderBuilder : MvxTextProviderBuilder
...
    protected override IDictionary<string, string> ResourceFiles
    {
        get
        {
            var dictionary = this.GetType()
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
                .Where(t => !t.Name.StartsWith("Base"))
                .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.Name);

            dictionary[Constants.Shared] = Constants.Shared;
            return dictionary;
        }
    }
```

And the main app registers it as being the text provider (thus faciliating the ViewModel-Json file automagic I assume) like this:

```
var builder = new TextProviderBuilder();
this.RegisterServiceInstance<IMvxTextProvider>(builder.TextProvider);
```

So obviously here I want to somehow use the same HelpPage resources, but be able to bind the controls on that help page with either (preferably) different json files with the same names as the parameters (Header1), or if necessary different parameters inside a single json file.

Many thanks!

Matthew

---

Edit: Stuart's solution below works perfectly. I just have to pass the name of the json file when I call RequestNavigate which comes through on the constructor of the ViewModel:

```
return new MvxRelayCommand(() => this.RequestNavigate<GeneralHelpViewModel>(new { helpKey = "DescribeAudioCrimeStatementHelpViewModel" }));
```

The only thing I had to do was create my own MvxLanguageBinder, as on my exact build of MvvmCross (not recent) the MvxLanguageBinder is private and not accessible.

I just copy and pasted the version from Stuart's link and used that:

https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localisation/MvxLanguageBinder.cs

Comment: I'm guessing you meant AXML not XAML :)

Comment: Xaml Axml Shmaml it's all the same to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this type of effect.

If you want to continue with separate json files, I would probably go for an approach like...

Change your binding to use a new TextSource - `CustomTextSource`

```
<TextView
       style="@style/HelpTextTitle"
       local:MvxBind="{'Text':'Path':'CustomTextSource','Converter':'Language','ConverterParameter':'Heading1'}}"
 />
```

Create your `HelpViewModel` so that it loads this `CustomTextSource` using the navigation parameter:

```
 public HelpViewModel (string helpKey)
 {
       CustomTextSource = new MvxLanguageBinder(Constants.GeneralNamespace, helpKey);
 }

 public IMvxLanguageBinder CustomTextSource { get; private set; }
```

Change your code that does the Text Resource loading to include your help files.

```
protected override IDictionary<string, string> ResourceFiles
{
    get
    {
        var dictionary = this.GetType()
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .Where(t => !t.Name.StartsWith("Base"))
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.Name);

        dictionary[Constants.Shared] = Constants.Shared;

        foreach (var additional in HelpFileList)
        {
             dictionary(additional) = additional;
        } 

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

( I'm assuming here that `HelpFileList` is a static list but you could also perhaps fine a way to do this using reflection.)

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to reorganise the help json into a single file, you could also consider writing a custom `IMvxLanguageBinder` which used your helpkey. Assuming you are using vNext, then the code for `MvxLanguageBinder` should be fairly straight-forward to adapt - the calls from axml come into [line 58](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localisation/MvxLanguageBinder.cs#L58)

---

Alternatively, if this really is just help text, then you could consider abandoning this xml and json approach - you could instead using embedded HTML displayed within a web browser widget - this might be the most flexible long-term solution which would allow for easiest content update in the future.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I tried your example, but ran into a problem because MvxLanguageBinder is a private class on MvxApplicationObject. I found the source for MvxLanguageBinder and copied that, but ran into another problem because MvxLanguageBinder calls the private method MvxApplicationObject.GetText. Am I right in thinking that this approach will only work with the latest version of your framework? I'm using v2 I think

Comment: assuming you are using v2/vnext then this was the source? https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localisation/MvxLanguageBinder.cs - which is the private method here? Confused - maybe try updating the question (comments too small)

Comment: Wow it works! Thanks Stuart! BTW I think on my build of MvvmCross the MvxLanguageBinder looks more like this: https://github.com/Zoldeper/Blooor/blob/master/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxApplicationObject.cs

Comment: Cool :) If you're on master, then you are on v1.